# UWP C# FileSavePicker -> DefaultFileExtension

Tags: c#, uwp

How to set the DefaultExtension? In the following code, the first entry is, so gif displayed. DefaultExtension but png. What should I change to make it work?

Code snippet:

```
var savePicker = new FileSavePicker
{
     SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary,
     CommitButtonText = "Save",
     DefaultFileExtension = ".png",
     SettingsIdentifier = "fsp1",
     SuggestedFileName = "MyImage"
};
savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("Gif-Image", new List<string> { ".gif" });
savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("Jpeg-Image", new List<string> { ".jpg" });
savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("Png-Image", new List<string> { ".png" });
savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("Ico-File", new List<string> { ".ico" });
savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("Bmp-Image", new List<string> { ".bmp" });
StorageFile file = await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();
```

Comment: We are investigating this issue, we will come back to report as soon as possible.

Comment: I've report this issue, please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for reporting this issue, we've confirmed that this is a logged issue. As currently implemented the DefaultFileExtension provides no meaningful use.

> What should I change to make it work?

If you want to make the default file extension to be .png, here is a workaround:

Move your code `savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("Png-Image", new List<string> { ".png" });` before `savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("Gif-Image", new List<string> { ".gif" });`. The first extension will be the default one in the list of `FileTypeChoices`.

Comment: Thanks for this information. The workaround but does not help me because the default extension is to be determined dynamically depending MimeType of image.

Comment: I am having the same requirement now, to @kendoo, even it's dynamically calculated, it can still be done (in an annoying way). However, I am disappointed to find out, after 3 years, this issue still exists!